# Troubleshoot OAuth 1.0 signature creation - can't reproduce Postman's successful signature

Tags: oauth

I've been looking at this for days and I need a fresh set of eyes. I know this is a common question, but most solutions appear to be "make sure the params are alphabetized" or "you missed an ampersand" and I'm pretty sure that's not my issue. As many other posters have stated, I can't get my sig to match what Postman generates.

1. All of the API calls I need are POST so the data I'm posting has no effect on the signature.
2. There are a couple params in the URL but according to the documentation those shouldn't be included for POSTs and indeed deleting them in Postman doesn't affect the sig
3. So the only things I have in the data portion are those necessary for all OAuth 1.0 sigs: consumer key, nonce, sig method, timestamp, token and version. easy to keep them straight
4. I need to use this in a custom scripting language/interface so no pre-built solution will work for me, but I have compared my code to several snippets I've found including java and javascript perl and another custom script. some do an alphabetical sort on the params for you, some require you to submit the params in order but they are all basically the same. If there was some tool that showed the pre-encoded string that would be a HUGE help.

I just posted this on upwork, I am happy to pay someone else to figure this out.

```
    //test values
requestURL = "https://myURL.com/subdirectory?param1=10&param2=0"
realm = "90210"
consKey = "555588884444777733336666"
token="111166662222777733338888"
sigMethod="HMAC-SHA256"
timestamp="1687965335"
nonce="10E7ZKnuxDf"
oauthVersion="1.0"
requestMethod = "POST"
consumer_Secret = "1"
token_secret = "2"

//strip params out of URL
url = requestURL.split("?")
reqParams = url[1]
baseURL = url[0]

//compile parameter string
data = ""
if requestMethod.upper() = "GET"
{
    data.append("{reqParams}&")
}
data.append("oauth_consumer_key={consKey}&")
data.append("oauth_nonce={nonce}&")
data.append("oauth_signature_method={sigMethod}&")
data.append("oauth_timestamp={timestamp}&")
data.append("oauth_token={token}&")
data.append("oauth_version={oauthVersion}")

//compile signature string
sigString = "{requestMethod.upper()}&{baseURL.urlencode()}&{data.urlencode()}"

//correct capitalization per OAuth 1.0 standard
sigString = sigString.replace("%3a","%3A").replace("%2f","%2F").replace("%3d","%3D")

//use proxy function to encrypt
proxy = getRestProxy()
oauthSig = proxy.EncodeHS256("{sigString}","{consumer_Secret}&{token_secret}")
oauthSig = "{oauthSig.trim()}" 
//(found a post saying their encoding added a hard return, doesn't seem to be an issue in my custom scripting language)

//re-urlencode. hashed values should have +,-,_,/
oauthSig = oauthSig.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
oauthSig = oauthSig.replace("+","%2B").replace("/","%2F")
oauthSig.append("%3D") //pad with =


//oauthSig=nyEyepA7lXiaR0HRZPMDQHTPdJEZMyMy7uEpEAIjFyw%3D //from my script
//oauth_signature="lv%2BbohpHYqR23LIs4XqFjyA3wtwxayZltoiYT6ss0ms%3D" //from postman
```

Comment: This is not a place for finding contractors. If you have a problem with your code, share that code.

Comment: added my code. yes, this custom script language is a pain and when I leave this job I will try to forget it as fast as I can. if you have any comments I would be happy to hear them. What I would really like is an interface where I can put in my values and see the correct base string before it is encoded. I assume my error is in there somewhere, but postman doesn't show that step.

Comment: with these test values, this is my unhashed string:   SIGSTRING=POST&https%3A%2F%2FmyURL.com%2Fsubdirectory&oauth_consumer_key%3D555588884444777733336666%26oauth_nonce%3D10E7ZKnuxDf%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1687965335%26oauth_token%3D111166662222777733338888%26oauth_version%3D1.0

Comment: From your post, I don't get what the problem is, what error are you getting? How are you testing, using Postman?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. I can run my requests successfully through Postman so to test I put the same values in Postman and my script and compare the output. I just can't get them to match. I don't actually expect anyone to see a problem in my code, I hope someone can point out the error in my sigString in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. The problem for me was one of assumptions, my code had no problems.

- Assumption number 2 above regarding what I would have called "querystring parameters" was incorrect. The OAuth specification stated that parameters in-line with the URL were used for GETs but not POSTs. It further stated that posted form data should not be included in the signature unless the body of the request was something besides "multipart/form-data". I was posting JSON in the request body with the appropriate content type so my interpretation of the standard was that I didn't need to include either the JSON or querystring parameters. This assumption was incorrect. The querystring parameters count as form-data and since my content type was JSON I fit into that exception where those parameters should be used in the signature.
- I did several tests in Postman adding, deleting and changing the
  params to confirm that nothing I changed there affected the code that shows in the code window UNLESS the request method was set to GET. This helped to confirm my incorrect assumption. This is now the second time I have seen specific cases where the code window did not reflect the actual request that Postman sends. In this case, it appears the person who wrote the function to build that code made the same incorrect assumption I did. I want to caution others that the values presented as working code should be taken with a grain of salt.

The following tools/resources were very useful. As I read through their code I saw that none of them excluded the querystring parameters for POSTs. I don't know if they were just simplistic, or if they understood the specifications better than I did.

--walkthrough that allows you to enter your values and you can watch how they are manipulated:

http://lti.tools/oauth/

--full javascript implementation, it doesn't show all the steps but still shows the pre-encoding signature string

https://github.com/johan/oauth-js

--PHP example showing just the signature creation. sample values are specific to oracle's API, but the code itself is universal.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1542835721.html#subsect_1542835740